How can I match vertices by attribute in Blender geometry nodes?
I'm fairly new to using geometry nodes, and I might be going about this the wrong way.
I need to separate my geometry into two parts (A & B). I've manipulated the geometry of part A, and now I want to merge part B back with A, matching the connecting vertices in B to where they are in the now modified A.
The reason I'm doing it this way is because I need to move certain faces along their normal, and I couldn't figure out how to do that at a corner because the vertices move along an averaged normal between the diferent face angles. So my plan was to split the geometry by what needs to move, and what doesn't. Before splitting them, I apllied a unique atrribute to every vertex. After splitting and modefying, the vertices where the parts used to connect share the same attribute values. Now I wnat to set the possition of the matches from B to the new positions in A, and then merge by distance.
Is there currently any way of doing this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
